# Sync Exchange to Caldav Server

Tags: python, exchange-server, caldav

I want to automatically synchronise an Exchange calendar to a caldav calendar. I know there are tools like Caldavsynchronizer, however I'm working on a MAC or Linux Server, where I canot use this Outlook plugin.

I did a small workaround by using the python libs icalendar and exchange lib. However, there I have problems with the synchronisation of recurring events.

Would be interesting if there is a native solution or another toolchain for this problem.